# Bootstrapper GUID

Tags: .net, wix, installation, bootstrapper, burn

WiX burn bootstrapper installs keys in either `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SOMEGUID` or `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SOMEGUID` depending on the architecture. I have noticed that `SOMEGUID` changes whenever I create a new build. I have some questions about `SOMEGUID`, and answers to any of the following would be tremendously helpful in case anyone might be able to shed some light:

1. How can I determine what `SOMEGUID` will be *before* installing from my bootstrapper?
2. Is it possible to hardcode `SOMEGUID`?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is determined from the BundleID property.
2. Nope, its set intermally and we dont have control over it.

Each time that you compile your bootstrapper project, it is assigned a new identity—a GUID called BundleId that you cannot change. In this respect, every bundle that you create is unique. The UpgradeCode attribute allows us to link two bootstrappers, making them related bundles. This relationship allows one bundle to detect and upgrade the installed packages of the other.

But what is the rational behind hardcoding the provider key? Just as in MSI's if two bundles have the same product code, it wont be able to handle major/minor upgrades properly.

Comment: Isaiah, this does not work. I have tried. The behavior is as follows: setting the `ProviderKey` on my `Bundle` element only sets the `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SOMEGUID\@BundleProviderKey` value, but `SOMEGUID` will always take on a different value from it, if `ProviderKey` is set. If it is not set, the `BundleProviderKey` is the same as `SOMEGUID`, but like I mentioned above, I would never know what that would materialize to when installed.

Comment: This question mentions the same problem with setting the ProviderKey, that is does not materialize the same value for `SOMEGUID`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26675457/how-to-find-guid-of-wix-burn-executable-for-programmatically-uninstall

Comment: The rational is complicated to explain, but I'll try to put it into words as best I can. Burn allows side-by-side installations of the same version of itself whenever I publish new builds to QA, and this caused me many headaches because ARP entries may increase from 1 to many for the same version of my bootstrapper. So, what I have done is I have hidden my bootstrapper from being visible in ARP and only show an MSI package it installs as visible. I am trying to keep the bootstrapper-to-MSI and MSI-to-bootstrapper relationship...

Comment: ...Ideally, if I install from my bootstrapper, I should be able to repair/remove from MSI, and vice-versa; if I install from MSI, I should be able to do repair/remove from bootstrapper. In my MSI file, I have a custom action that uninstalls the bootstrapper from its Uninstall key using a simple `cmd` under certain conditions (such as if its a removal, and not an upgrade, etc.), but on install, I need to "trick" the bootstrapper into thinking that it is installed, if I first install from MSI.

Comment: Basically, I am at the point where if I install from MSI first, and then run the bootstrapper, the bootstrapper still shows Install option; clicking install just registers its Uninstall keys in the registry. I just need a way to have it go directly to the uninstall/repair screen...one way to do this is to add a registry key in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SOMEGUID` with `@Installed` (DWORD) = 1.

Comment: Yup you are right, provider key is not same as the GUID. Looks like thats something which is managed within the BA. Are you using same upgradecode across different versions of the Bundle? If they have the same upgradecode, then the bundle should detect the older bundle and will be able to do upgrade

Comment: Upgrades are fine; yes, they all use the same upgrade code. The problem is this: I run my *.msi* setup file, it installs my application (this *.msi* file enforces that prerequisites are installed by erroring out; prerequisites are packaged in my bundle). Ultimately, the whole goal of my bootstrapper bundle is to install my *.msi* package, so it installs a few *.exe* packages before the *.msi*, but: If the *.msi* is installed prior to running the bootstrapper, the bootstrapper goes to an Install screen; ideally, I'd like to trick the bootstrapper into going to an Uninstall or Repair screen...

Comment: ...by registering the bootstrapper's *\Uninstall* key through a final custom action in my *.msi* if the key is not already present, since, my company supplies both the *.msi* package and *.exe* bootstrapper package to customers; which means I need to enforce this relationship between bootstrapper and *.msi*. Does this make sense at all?

Comment: If the MSI is already installed and when you run the bundle again, if your MSI does handle upgrades/repair properly..then it should be straight forward right? even though it takes to the install bundle screen first time, it shuoldnt cause any issues.

Comment: The only issue is that the bootstrapped launches with the Install screen. Like you said, there is no loss in functionality because you can Install the bootstrapper and it will register itself, and relaunching it thereafter will bring you to an Uninstall and Repair screen...but I would still like my bootstrapper to launch into the Uninstall and Repair window first, since it makes more sense this way. The bootstrapper should be smart enough to detect when all bundled packages are installed OR there should be a way to pre-register the bootstrapper from another package.

Comment: @Alexandru The bootstrapper is a package manager and it has not been installed yet. So, the bootstrapper starts at the install screen because the user is being asked whether to install the bootstrapper and bump the usage count of the packages that it references.

Comment: @TomBlodget I know Tom; I have said above, that its detection mechanism for this is by checking a registry key in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SOMEGUID` with `@Installed` (DWORD) = 1. I would like to trick it to not behave this way, by manually adding in that key, but to do that, I need to hardcode `SOMEGUID`. That's my problem at the moment, is how to hardcode `SOMEGUID`.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Wix 3.11 version and used following steps to include custom ProviderKey for Bundle
1. Add reference for WixDependancy.dll to Project.
2. Add extra markup for dll file added as

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" xmlns:dep="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/DependencyExtension">
```

3.Then use the keyword dep to define Provide key as

```
<Bundle Name="ABC" ParentName="ParentName" Version="x.x.x." Manufacturer="ABC Company" UpgradeCode="A-a-a-a-a" dep:ProviderKey="b-b-b-b-b">
```

Answer (score 0):

The Bundle ID is available in [Burn build in variable](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables/) `WixBundleProviderKey`.
You can pass that variable as public property to the MSI installer to find Bundle Package Cache location in Registry and use that to build you uninstall command.

##### Bootstrapper project

Bundle.wxs

```xml
<Bundle>
    ...
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="PathToYourApplication.msi">
        <MsiProperty Name='BUNDLE_ID' Value='[WixBundleProviderKey]'/>
    </MsiPackage>
</Bundle
```

##### Installer project

Product.wxs

```xml
<Wix>
    <Product>
        ...
        <!-- Public Property (value will be overwritten with variable from the bootstrapper during installation) -->
        <Property Id="BUNDLE_ID" Value="default" />

        <!-- Searching for Package Cache location for the current bundle -->
        <!-- Value would be string like 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{BundleIdGuid}\YourApplication.exe' -->
        <Property Id="BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH">
            <RegistrySearch Id="BundleCachePath"
                            Root="HKLM"
                            Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[BUNDLE_ID]"
                            Name="BundleCachePath"
                            Type="raw" />
        </Property>

        ...
        <!-- Use [BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH] variable to construct the uninstall command, for instance for the uninstall shortcut -->
        <Shortcut Id="UninstallShortcut"
                  Name="Uninstall My Application"
                  Target="[BUNDLE_CACHE_PATH]"
                  Arguments="/uninstall" />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```